# hook_entity_predelete never called

Tags: entities, hooks

I have tried to create a hook that deletes an entity of type *notification* when the entity of type *deadline* is deleted, but the hook never gets called. Entities of type *notification* have one referenced entity of type *deadline*.

 I have tried to clear the cache several times but without any luck. Am I missing something?

```
 /**
   * Implements hook_entity_predelete().
   *
   */
  function dib_notifications_entity_predelete(EntityInterface $entity) {
    if ($entity->bundle() == 'deadline') {
      $array = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getStorage('node')
        ->loadByProperties
        (['type' => 'notification',
          'title' => $entity->label()
        ]);
      $notification=reset($array);
      $notification->delete();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure the hook is never called? Could it be that the hook is being called, but the code inside isn't doing what you expect? Where is this code located?

Comment: Unless you have some core patches, it's definitely called (see `EntityStorageBase::delete`). Which suggests your module is not enabled, or the naming convention for the hook is off. Also, why pre-delete? Wouldn't you want this post-delete, i.e. after you've confirmed the deadline deletion was actually successful?